# php giving strange output

Tags: php, mysql

So after migrating to a different host, exporting and importing database, fixing links, I am getting some strange output of my php which worked fine on the previous host.

php connect:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","dbname_user","password");
mysql_select_db("dbname",$con);
if (mysql_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error();
}
?>
```

php db call:

```
<?php
//print table info
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pizzas";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
$firstRow = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
if($row["enabled"] == 1){
if($firstRow == 0){
echo '<tr><td class="spacer">~</td></tr>';
}
echo '<tr><td class="title">'.$row['name'].'</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td class="description">'.$row['description'].'</td></tr>';
if($row['priceMax']){
echo '<tr><td class="price">£'.$row['price'].' - £'.$row['priceMax'].'</td></tr>';
}
elseif($row['price']){
echo '<tr><td class="price">£'.$row['price'].'</td></tr>';
}
$firstRow = 0;
}
}
?>
```

Output in html:

> '; } echo ''; echo ''; if($row['priceMax']){ echo ''; }
>   elseif($row['price']){ echo ''; } $firstRow = 0; } } ?> ~
>   '.$row['name'].' '.$row['description'].' £'.$row['price'].' -
>   £'.$row['priceMax'].' £'.$row['price'].'

Can anyone decipher what exactly is going wrong here? I have no idea what is giving this strange output.

EDIT: 
Fixed to make all mysql and no mysqli. Same output.
Changed all from mysql to mysqli. No change.
Included error reporting. No extra info.
If ?php wasn't implemented as a keyword as suggested then wouldn't all the code be printed? This is what is so confusing is that some code is obviously being read but some not.

phpinfo:

```
> PHP Logo PHP Version 5.4.26
> 
> System    Linux metro703.hostmetro.com
> 2.6.32-531.1.2.lve1.2.54.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 25 07:41:27 EDT 2014 x86_64 Build Date     Mar 29 2014 04:36:14 Configure Command
>   './configure' '--disable-fileinfo' '--enable-bcmath'
> '--enable-calendar' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp'
> '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-intl' '--enable-libxml'
> '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--enable-soap'
> '--enable-sockets' '--enable-wddx' '--enable-zip'
> '--prefix=/usr/local' '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs'
> '--with-curl=/opt/curlssl/' '--with-curlwrappers'
> '--with-enchant=/usr' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-gd'
> '--with-gettext' '--with-icu-dir=/usr'
> '--with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/' '--with-imap-ssl=/usr'
> '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-kerberos' '--with-libdir=lib64'
> '--with-libexpat-dir=/usr' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2'
> '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/' '--with-mcrypt=/opt/libmcrypt/'
> '--with-mm=/opt/mm/' '--with-mysql=/usr'
> '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'
> '--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config' '--with-openssl=/usr'
> '--with-openssl-dir=/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/opt/pcre'
> '--with-pdo-mysql=shared' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared' '--with-pic'
> '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-pspell' '--with-tidy=/opt/tidy/'
> '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-xsl=/opt/xslt/'
> '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr' Server API   CGI/FastCGI Virtual
> Directory Support     disabled Configuration File (php.ini) Path
>   /usr/local/lib Loaded Configuration File    /usr/local/lib/php.ini Scan
> this dir for additional .ini files    (none) Additional .ini files
> parsed    (none) PHP API  20100412 PHP Extension  20100525 Zend
> Extension     220100525 Zend Extension Build  API220100525,NTS PHP
> Extension Build   API20100525,NTS Debug Build     no Thread Safety
>   disabled Zend Signal Handling   disabled Zend Memory Manager    enabled
> Zend Multibyte Support    provided by mbstring IPv6 Support   enabled
> DTrace Support    disabled Registered PHP Streams compress.zlib, dict,
> ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, smtp,
> smtps, telnet, tftp, php, file, glob, data, phar, zip Registered
> Stream Socket Transports  tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls
> Registered Stream Filters zlib.*, convert.iconv.*, mcrypt.*,
> mdecrypt.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower,
> string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk
> 
> Zend logo This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language
> Engine: Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
>     with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.4.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by ionCube Ltd., and
>     with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2013, by Zend Technologies
> 
> PHP Credits Configuration bcmath BCMath support   enabled
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value bcmath.scale   0   0
> 
> calendar Calendar support     enabled
> 
> cgi-fcgi Directive    Local Value Master Value cgi.check_shebang_line 1   1
> cgi.discard_path  0   0 cgi.fix_pathinfo  1   1 cgi.force_redirect    1   1
> cgi.nph   0   0 cgi.redirect_status_env   no value    no value
> cgi.rfc2616_headers   0   0 fastcgi.logging   1   1
> 
> Core PHP Version  5.4.26
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value allow_url_fopen    On  On
> allow_url_include Off Off always_populate_raw_post_data   Off Off
> arg_separator.input   &   & arg_separator.output  &   & asp_tags  Off Off
> auto_append_file  no value    no value auto_globals_jit   On  On
> auto_prepend_file no value    no value browscap   no value    no value
> default_charset   no value    no value default_mimetype   text/html   text/html
> disable_classes   no value    no value
> disable_functions eval,exec,passthru,shell_exec,socket_create,symlink eval,exec,passthru,shell_exec,socket_create,symlink
> display_errors    On  On display_startup_errors   Off Off doc_root    no
> value no value docref_ext no value    no value docref_root    no value    no
> value enable_dl   On  On enable_post_data_reading On  On
> error_append_string   no value    no value error_log  error_log   error_log
> error_prepend_string  no value    no value error_reporting    8183    8183
> exit_on_timeout   Off Off expose_php  On  On
> extension_dir /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525 /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525
> file_uploads  On  On highlight.comment    #FF8000 #FF8000
> highlight.default #0000BB #0000BB highlight.html  #000000 #000000
> highlight.keyword #007700 #007700 highlight.string    #DD0000 #DD0000
> html_errors   On  On ignore_repeated_errors   Off Off
> ignore_repeated_source    Off Off ignore_user_abort   Off Off
> implicit_flush    Off Off
> include_path  .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php   .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php
> log_errors    On  On log_errors_max_len   1024    1024
> mail.add_x_header Off Off mail.force_extra_parameters no value    no
> value mail.log    no value    no value max_execution_time 30  30
> max_file_uploads  20  20 max_input_nesting_level  64  64
> max_input_time    60  60 max_input_vars   1000    1000 memory_limit   32M 32M
> open_basedir  no value    no value output_buffering   no value    no value
> output_handler    no value    no value post_max_size  8M  8M precision    12  12
> realpath_cache_size   16K 16K realpath_cache_ttl  120 120
> register_argc_argv    On  On report_memleaks  On  On report_zend_debug    On  On
> request_order no value    no value sendmail_from  no value    no value
> sendmail_path /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
> serialize_precision   100 100 short_open_tag  On  On
> SMTP  localhost   localhost smtp_port 25  25 sql.safe_mode    Off Off
> track_errors  Off Off unserialize_callback_func   no value    no value
> upload_max_filesize   20M 20M upload_tmp_dir  no value    no value
> user_dir  no value    no value user_ini.cache_ttl 300 300
> user_ini.filename .user.ini   .user.ini variables_order   EGPCS   EGPCS
> xmlrpc_error_number   0   0 xmlrpc_errors Off Off
> zend.detect_unicode   On  On zend.enable_gc   On  On zend.multibyte   Off Off
> zend.script_encoding  no value    no value
> 
> ctype ctype functions     enabled
> 
> curl cURL support     enabled cURL Information    7.24.0 Age  3 Features
> AsynchDNS     No Debug    No GSS-Negotiate    No IDN  Yes IPv6    Yes Largefile
>   Yes NTLM    Yes SPNEGO  No SSL  Yes SSPI    No krb4     No libz     Yes
> CharConv  No Protocols    dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https,
> imap, imaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp Host
>   x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu SSL Version    OpenSSL/1.0.1e ZLib Version
>   1.2.3
> 
> date date/time support    enabled "Olson" Timezone Database Version
>   2013.9 Timezone Database    internal Default timezone   UTC
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value
> date.default_latitude 31.7667 31.7667
> date.default_longitude    35.2333 35.2333
> date.sunrise_zenith   90.583333   90.583333
> date.sunset_zenith    90.583333   90.583333 date.timezone UTC UTC
> 
> dom DOM/XML   enabled DOM/XML API Version     20031129 libxml Version
>   2.9.0 HTML Support  enabled XPath Support   enabled XPointer Support    enabled Schema Support  enabled RelaxNG Support     enabled
> 
> enchant enchant support   enabled Version     1.1.0 Libenchant Version
>   1.5.x Revision  $Id: 6de2feac8047059326b85565067ecdba8fb4f363 $
> 
> myspell   Myspell Provider    /usr/lib64/enchant/libenchant_myspell.so
> 
> ereg Regex Library    Bundled library enabled
> 
> exif EXIF Support     enabled EXIF Version    1.4 $Id$ Supported EXIF
> Version   0220 Supported filetypes    JPEG,TIFF
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value exif.decode_jis_intel  JIS JIS
> exif.decode_jis_motorola  JIS JIS
> exif.decode_unicode_intel UCS-2LE UCS-2LE
> exif.decode_unicode_motorola  UCS-2BE UCS-2BE exif.encode_jis no
> value no value exif.encode_unicode    ISO-8859-15 ISO-8859-15
> 
> filter Input Validation and Filtering     enabled Revision    $Id:
> ad78b4a085153b8c7f4d6db5dc69df40e969c343 $
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value
> filter.default    unsafe_raw  unsafe_raw filter.default_flags no value    no
> value
> 
> ftp FTP support   enabled
> 
> gd GD Support     enabled GD Version  bundled (2.1.0 compatible) FreeType
> Support   enabled FreeType Linkage    with freetype FreeType Version
>   2.3.11 GIF Read Support     enabled GIF Create Support  enabled JPEG Support    enabled libJPEG Version     6b PNG Support  enabled libPNG
> Version   1.2.49 WBMP Support     enabled XPM Support     enabled libXpm
> Version   30411 XBM Support   enabled
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value gd.jpeg_ignore_warning 0   0
> 
> gettext GetText Support   enabled
> 
> hash hash support     enabled Hashing Engines     md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224
> sha256 sha384 sha512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool
> tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4
> snefru snefru256 gost adler32 crc32 crc32b fnv132 fnv164 joaat
> haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4
> haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5
> haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5
> 
> iconv iconv support   enabled iconv implementation    glibc iconv library
> version   2.12
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value
> iconv.input_encoding  ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
> iconv.internal_encoding   ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
> iconv.output_encoding ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
> 
> imap IMAP c-Client Version    2007f SSL Support   enabled Kerberos
> Support   enabled
> 
> intl Internationalization support enabled version     1.1.0 ICU version
>   4.2.1
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value intl.default_locale    no value    no
> value intl.error_level    0   0
> 
> json json support     enabled json version    1.2.1
> 
> libxml libXML support     active libXML Compiled Version  2.9.0 libXML
> Loaded Version    20900 libXML streams    enabled
> 
> mbstring Multibyte Support    enabled Multibyte string engine     libmbfl
> HTTP input encoding translation   disabled libmbfl version    1.3.2
> 
> mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and
> converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public
> License version 2.1.
> 
> Multibyte (japanese) regex support    enabled Multibyte regex
> (oniguruma) backtrack check   On Multibyte regex (oniguruma) version
>   4.7.1
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value mbstring.detect_order  no value    no
> value mbstring.encoding_translation   Off Off mbstring.func_overload  0   0
> mbstring.http_input   pass    pass mbstring.http_output   pass    pass
> mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes   ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml) ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml)
> mbstring.internal_encoding    no value    no value
> mbstring.language neutral neutral mbstring.strict_detection   Off Off
> mbstring.substitute_character no value    no value
> 
> mcrypt mcrypt support enabled mcrypt_filter support   enabled Version
>   2.5.8 Api No    20021217 Supported ciphers  cast-128 gost rijndael-128 twofish arcfour cast-256 loki97 rijndael-192 saferplus wake
> blowfish-compat des rijndael-256 serpent xtea blowfish enigma rc2
> tripledes Supported modes     cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb nofb ofb stream
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value mcrypt.algorithms_dir  no value    no
> value mcrypt.modes_dir    no value    no value
> 
> mysql MySQL Support   enabled Active Persistent Links     0 Active Links  0
> Client API version    5.5.36 MYSQL_MODULE_TYPE    external MYSQL_SOCKET
>   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock MYSQL_INCLUDE     -I/usr/include/mysql
> MYSQL_LIBS    -L/usr/lib64 -lmysqlclient
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value mysql.allow_local_infile   On  On
> mysql.allow_persistent    On  On mysql.connect_timeout    60  60
> mysql.default_host    no value    no value mysql.default_password no
> value no value mysql.default_port no value    no value
> mysql.default_socket  /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
> mysql.default_user    no value    no value
> mysql.max_links   Unlimited   Unlimited
> mysql.max_persistent  Unlimited   Unlimited mysql.trace_mode  Off Off
> 
> mysqli MysqlI Support enabled Client API library version  5.5.36
> Active Persistent Links   0 Inactive Persistent Links     0 Active Links
>   0 Client API header version     5.5.36 MYSQLI_SOCKET
>   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value mysqli.allow_local_infile  On  On
> mysqli.allow_persistent   On  On mysqli.default_host  no value    no value
> mysqli.default_port   3306    3306 mysqli.default_pw  no value    no value
> mysqli.default_socket /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
> mysqli.default_user   no value    no value
> mysqli.max_links  Unlimited   Unlimited
> mysqli.max_persistent Unlimited   Unlimited mysqli.reconnect  Off Off
> 
> mysqlnd mysqlnd   enabled Version     mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id:
> c85105d7c6f7d70d609bb4c000257868a40840ab $ Compression    supported SSL
>   supported Command buffer size   4096 Read buffer size   32768 Read
> timeout   31536000 Collecting statistics  Yes Collecting memory
> statistics    No Tracing  n/a Loaded plugins
>   mysqlnd,example,debug_trace,auth_plugin_mysql_native_password,auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password
> API Extensions    pdo_mysql
> 
> mysqlnd statistics     bytes_sent     0 bytes_received    0 packets_sent  0
> packets_received  0 protocol_overhead_in  0 protocol_overhead_out     0
> bytes_received_ok_packet  0 bytes_received_eof_packet     0
> bytes_received_rset_header_packet     0
> bytes_received_rset_field_meta_packet     0
> bytes_received_rset_row_packet    0
> bytes_received_prepare_response_packet    0
> bytes_received_change_user_packet     0 packets_sent_command  0
> packets_received_ok   0 packets_received_eof  0
> packets_received_rset_header  0 packets_received_rset_field_meta  0
> packets_received_rset_row     0 packets_received_prepare_response     0
> packets_received_change_user  0 result_set_queries    0
> non_result_set_queries    0 no_index_used     0 bad_index_used    0
> slow_queries  0 buffered_sets     0 unbuffered_sets   0 ps_buffered_sets
>   0 ps_unbuffered_sets    0 flushed_normal_sets   0 flushed_ps_sets   0
> ps_prepared_never_executed    0 ps_prepared_once_executed     0
> rows_fetched_from_server_normal   0 rows_fetched_from_server_ps   0
> rows_buffered_from_client_normal  0 rows_buffered_from_client_ps  0
> rows_fetched_from_client_normal_buffered  0
> rows_fetched_from_client_normal_unbuffered    0
> rows_fetched_from_client_ps_buffered  0
> rows_fetched_from_client_ps_unbuffered    0
> rows_fetched_from_client_ps_cursor    0 rows_affected_normal  0
> rows_affected_ps  0 rows_skipped_normal   0 rows_skipped_ps   0
> copy_on_write_saved   0 copy_on_write_performed   0
> command_buffer_too_small  0 connect_success   0 connect_failure   0
> connection_reused     0 reconnect     0 pconnect_success  0
> active_connections    0 active_persistent_connections     0 explicit_close
>   0 implicit_close    0 disconnect_close  0 in_middle_of_command_close    0
> explicit_free_result  0 implicit_free_result  0 explicit_stmt_close   0
> implicit_stmt_close   0 mem_emalloc_count     0 mem_emalloc_amount    0
> mem_ecalloc_count     0 mem_ecalloc_amount    0 mem_erealloc_count    0
> mem_erealloc_amount   0 mem_efree_count   0 mem_efree_amount  0
> mem_malloc_count  0 mem_malloc_amount     0 mem_calloc_count  0
> mem_calloc_amount     0 mem_realloc_count     0 mem_realloc_amount    0
> mem_free_count    0 mem_free_amount   0 mem_estrndup_count    0
> mem_strndup_count     0 mem_estndup_count     0 mem_strdup_count  0
> proto_text_fetched_null   0 proto_text_fetched_bit    0
> proto_text_fetched_tinyint    0 proto_text_fetched_short  0
> proto_text_fetched_int24  0 proto_text_fetched_int    0
> proto_text_fetched_bigint     0 proto_text_fetched_decimal    0
> proto_text_fetched_float  0 proto_text_fetched_double     0
> proto_text_fetched_date   0 proto_text_fetched_year   0
> proto_text_fetched_time   0 proto_text_fetched_datetime   0
> proto_text_fetched_timestamp  0 proto_text_fetched_string     0
> proto_text_fetched_blob   0 proto_text_fetched_enum   0
> proto_text_fetched_set    0 proto_text_fetched_geometry   0
> proto_text_fetched_other  0 proto_binary_fetched_null     0
> proto_binary_fetched_bit  0 proto_binary_fetched_tinyint  0
> proto_binary_fetched_short    0 proto_binary_fetched_int24    0
> proto_binary_fetched_int  0 proto_binary_fetched_bigint   0
> proto_binary_fetched_decimal  0 proto_binary_fetched_float    0
> proto_binary_fetched_double   0 proto_binary_fetched_date     0
> proto_binary_fetched_year     0 proto_binary_fetched_time     0
> proto_binary_fetched_datetime     0 proto_binary_fetched_timestamp    0
> proto_binary_fetched_string   0 proto_binary_fetched_blob     0
> proto_binary_fetched_enum     0 proto_binary_fetched_set  0
> proto_binary_fetched_geometry     0 proto_binary_fetched_other    0
> init_command_executed_count   0 init_command_failed_count     0 com_quit
>   0 com_init_db   0 com_query     0 com_field_list    0 com_create_db     0
> com_drop_db   0 com_refresh   0 com_shutdown  0 com_statistics    0
> com_process_info  0 com_connect   0 com_process_kill  0 com_debug     0
> com_ping  0 com_time  0 com_delayed_insert    0 com_change_user   0
> com_binlog_dump   0 com_table_dump    0 com_connect_out   0
> com_register_slave    0 com_stmt_prepare  0 com_stmt_execute  0
> com_stmt_send_long_data   0 com_stmt_close    0 com_stmt_reset    0
> com_stmt_set_option   0 com_stmt_fetch    0 com_deamon    0
> bytes_received_real_data_normal   0 bytes_received_real_data_ps   0
> 
> example statistics     stat1  0 stat2     0
> 
> openssl OpenSSL support   enabled OpenSSL Library Version     OpenSSL
> 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013 OpenSSL Header Version    OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
> 
> pcre PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support   enabled PCRE
> Library Version   8.21 2011-12-12
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value
> pcre.backtrack_limit  1000000 1000000
> pcre.recursion_limit  100000  100000
> 
> PDO PDO support   enabled PDO drivers     sqlite, mysql
> 
> pdo_mysql PDO Driver for MySQL    enabled Client API version  mysqlnd
> 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: c85105d7c6f7d70d609bb4c000257868a40840ab $
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value
> pdo_mysql.default_socket  /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
> 
> pdo_sqlite PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x  enabled SQLite Library  3.7.7.1
> 
> Phar Phar: PHP Archive support    enabled Phar EXT version    2.0.1 Phar
> API version   1.1.1 SVN revision  $Id:
> ec823514107160b7e6fabc519594012657a2db91 $ Phar-based phar archives
>   enabled Tar-based phar archives     enabled ZIP-based phar archives
>   enabled gzip compression    enabled bzip2 compression   disabled
> (install pecl/bz2) OpenSSL support    enabled
> 
> Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik. Phar
> fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger. Portions of tar
> implementation Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle.
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value phar.cache_list    no value    no value
> phar.readonly On  On phar.require_hash    On  On
> 
> posix Revision    $Id: 1dfa9997ed76804e53c91e0ce862f3707617b6ed $
> 
> pspell PSpell Support     enabled
> 
> Reflection Reflection enabled Version     $Id:
> f6367cdb4e3f392af4a6d441a6641de87c2e50c4 $
> 
> session Session Support   enabled Registered save handlers    files user
> mm Registered serializer handlers     php php_binary wddx
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value session.auto_start Off Off
> session.cache_expire  180 180 session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
> session.cookie_domain no value    no value
> session.cookie_httponly   Off Off session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
> session.cookie_path   /   / session.cookie_secure Off Off
> session.entropy_file  no value    no value session.entropy_length 0   0
> session.gc_divisor    100 100 session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
> session.gc_probability    1   1 session.hash_bits_per_character   4   4
> session.hash_function 0   0 session.name  PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
> session.referer_check no value    no value
> session.save_handler  files   files session.save_path /tmp    /tmp
> session.serialize_handler php php
> session.upload_progress.cleanup   On  On
> session.upload_progress.enabled   On  On
> session.upload_progress.freq  1%  1%
> session.upload_progress.min_freq  1   1
> session.upload_progress.name  PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_
> session.use_cookies   On  On session.use_only_cookies On  On
> session.use_trans_sid 0   0
> 
> SimpleXML Simplexml support   enabled Revision    $Id:
> b9966ddccead3e8bb7666aae9de01fe3d687b21a $ Schema support     enabled
> 
> soap Soap Client  enabled Soap Server     enabled
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value soap.wsdl_cache    1   1
> soap.wsdl_cache_dir   /tmp    /tmp soap.wsdl_cache_enabled    1   1
> soap.wsdl_cache_limit 5   5 soap.wsdl_cache_ttl   86400   86400
> 
> sockets Sockets Support   enabled
> 
> SPL SPL support   enabled Interfaces  Countable, OuterIterator,
> RecursiveIterator, SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject Classes
>   AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException,
> BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator,
> DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator,
> FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator,
> InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException,
> LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator,
> OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException,
> ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator,
> RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator,
> RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator,
> RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator,
> RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException,
> SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray,
> SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue,
> SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException,
> UnexpectedValueException
> 
> sqlite3 SQLite3 support   enabled SQLite3 module version  0.7 SQLite
> Library   3.7.7.1
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value sqlite3.extension_dir  no value    no
> value
> 
> standard Dynamic Library Support  enabled Path to sendmail
>   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value assert.active  1   1 assert.bail   0   0
> assert.callback   no value    no value assert.quiet_eval  0   0
> assert.warning    1   1 auto_detect_line_endings  0   0
> default_socket_timeout    60  60 from no value    no value
> url_rewriter.tags a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=,fieldset=    a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=,fieldset=
> user_agent    no value    no value
> 
> tidy Tidy support enabled libTidy Release     25 March 2009 Extension
> Version   2.0 ($Id$)
> 
> Directive Local Value Master Value tidy.clean_output  0   0
> tidy.default_config   no value    no value
> 
> tokenizer Tokenizer Support   enabled
> 
> wddx WDDX Support enabled WDDX Session Serializer     enabled
> 
> xml XML Support   active XML Namespace Support    active EXPAT Version
>   expat_2.0.1
> 
> xmlreader XMLReader   enabled
> 
> xmlrpc core library version   xmlrpc-epi v. 0.51 php extension version
>   0.51 author     Dan Libby homepage  http://xmlrpc-epi.sourceforge.net open sourced by   Epinions.com
> 
> xmlwriter XMLWriter   enabled
> 
> xsl XSL   enabled libxslt Version     1.1.27 libxslt compiled against
> libxml Version    2.9.0 EXSLT     enabled libexslt Version    1.1.27
> 
> Zend Guard Loader Zend Guard Loader   enabled License Path    no value
> Obfuscation level     0
> 
> 
> 
> 
> PHP License
> 
> This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
> it under the terms of the PHP License as published by the PHP Group
> and included in the distribution in the file: LICENSE
> 
> This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
> WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
> MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
> 
> If you did not receive a copy of the PHP license, or have any
> questions about PHP licensing, please contact license@php.net.
```

Comment: can you know me your file path.

Comment: PHP version? Is it the same if you change all echo calls to print()? phpinfo() output will greatly help everyone.

Comment: changed all echo to print. same output :/

Comment: @user3672543 you haven't initialized <table>

Comment: the <table> is created 1 line before the php

Answer (score 2):

You are using `mysqli_connect` and querying the table with `mysql_query`. That is wrong. Please use [mysqli_query](http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli.query.php) and [mysqli_fetch_array](http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

query should become:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

fetching records

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to make a file that contains just

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

and see if that works and gives you your php configuration?

I would guess that something with your PHP or your webserver settings is wrong. Perhaps `<?php` is not activated as a trigger to use PHP.

Also you can add

```
error_reporting(-1);
```

to the beginning of your script (after the first `<?php`) and see if you get additional messages. (This level of error reporting should not be used in a production environment!)

Comment: and name it with what extension? .php?

Comment: created info.php, uploaded to server, no change.

Comment: sorry i am dumb xD now updating to include phpinfo print

Comment: What do you see if you open the page in your web browser?

Answer (score 0):

Change your connect codes with these

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","dbname_user","password");
    mysql_select_db("dbname",$con);
    if (mysql_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error();
    }
?>
```

It is becaause you are connecting with mysqli functions and executing with mysql functions. It should all be in mysql or mysqli functions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you opened the page in the browser such that it is served from the server

(your browser shows something like `http://` in the address line)

and that you did NOT open it from your hard drive

(your browser shows something like `file://` in the address line)?

Comment: this is the browser output. go check if you want. www.lacaverna.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

Problem wasn't with code. It was to do with the server using suPHP and having to include

```
=========
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php .html .htm
=========
```

into the .htaccess file.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help though!